# XML parsing in APEX and display the VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, webservices, xml

Please explain me how to do xml parsing into apex to show this XML data into visualforce page and also insert this XML Data into custom object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
<soapenv:Header>
    <LimitInfoHeader>
        <limitInfo>
            <current>343</current>
            <limit>5000000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
        </limitInfo>
    </LimitInfoHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <queryResponse>
        <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
            <done>true</done>
            <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
            <records xsi:type="sf:sObject"> 
                <sf:type>Opportunity</sf:type>
                <sf:Id>006q0000002DwTHAA0</sf:Id>
                <sf:Id>006q0000002DwTHAA0</sf:Id>
            </records>
            <size>1</size>
        </result>
    </queryResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

class :

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap sp = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();

String username = 'username';
String password = 'pwd+ST';

partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = sp.login(username, password);

partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element header=new partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
header.sessionId=loginResult.sessionId; 
sp.SessionHeader = Header;
sp.endpoint_x = loginResult.serverUrl;
partnerSoapSforceCom.QueryResult qr = sp.query('Select Id from opportunity limit 1');
System.debug('Number of Query results:' + qr);
system.debug('qr: '+sp.query('SELECT Id FROM opportunity limit 1 '));
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am unable to display the Opportunity ID in Visualforce page, but its displaying developer console logs.